# Matrix calculation between list objects in R

Tags: r, list, matrix, apply, matrix-multiplication

I have created list of objects in `R` as follows:

```
set.seed(1234)
data <- matrix(rnorm(3*4,mean=0,sd=1), 3, 4) 
results <- lapply(1:ncol(data), function(i) outer(data[, i], data[, i]))
```

all 4 list objects have `dim=3x3`. I also have the following matrix `matr <- matrix(c(2,4,6,8),ncol=4)`, where each value corresponds to the above list objects.

Then, I use this equation `matr[,1]*matr[,2]*results[[1]]*results[[2]]` between the first two objects in order to create the below matrix

```
          [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
[1,] 64.135122 2.6966755 12.4307531
[2,]  2.696676 0.1133865  0.5226732
[3,] 12.430753 0.5226732  2.4093448
```

How can I calculate the above equation for all all possible object combinations and save them to a new list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `combn` to create pairwise combination on the sequence of the `list`, extract the elements and do the multiplication

```
new_lst <- combn(seq_along(results), 2, \(i) matr[,i[1]] * matr[,i[2]] * 
    results[[i[1]]] * results[[i[2]]], simplify = FALSE)
names(new_lst) <- combn(seq_along(results), 2, paste, collapse="_")
```

-output

```
> new_lst
$`1_2`
          [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
[1,] 64.135122 2.6966755 12.4307531
[2,]  2.696676 0.1133865  0.5226732
[3,] 12.430753 0.5226732  2.4093448

$`1_3`
          [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
[1,]  5.775451 -1.2624981 -5.095849
[2,] -1.262498  0.2759787  1.113939
[3,] -5.095849  1.1139391  4.496217

$`1_4`
          [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  18.46710 -2.275650 -18.610758
[2,]  -2.27565  0.280422   2.293352
[3,] -18.61076  2.293352  18.755530

$`2_3`
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 43.621251 -7.589849 -9.242303
[2,] -7.589849  1.320590  1.608108
[3,] -9.242303  1.608108  1.958223

$`2_4`
          [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] 139.47970 -13.680683 -33.754187
[2,] -13.68068   1.341852   3.310735
[3,] -33.75419   3.310735   8.168537

$`3_4`
          [,1]     [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 12.560327 6.404863 13.837154
[2,]  6.404863 3.266019  7.055953
[3,] 13.837154 7.055953 15.243778
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work perfectly. Is there any way to make the objects displayed as the name of the objects they combine? Meaning instead of [[1]], [[2]],...,[[6]], to be [[1,2]],[[1,3]],...,[[3,4]]?

Comment: Hello @akrun, If I wanted to find only the combinations between the first matrix and all others i.e., `1_1`, `1_2`, `1_3`, `1_4`, and not all the combinations, what should I change in your code? Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried it but I do not get the same results, maybe I rephrase it wrong. I want to calculate only the matrices `1_2`, `1_3`, `1_4` that you produced in the `new_lst`

Comment: Hello @akrun...If I wanted to perform the procedure for all possible combinations, i.e., `1_1`, `1_2`,`1_3`,`1_4`, `2_1`,...,`4_4`, what should i change in your code?

Comment: thanks, that works perfectly. How can I redefine the `names(new_lst)` in order to work properly on this `apply` function?